# ASP .Net MVC-application: how to display to the user when a boolean property ("watched") of a db-entity ("lesson) is true

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, linq, if-statement

I want to show to the web screen that when I click in each lesson, it can be add to the table UserAndLesson in database (I checked duplicate case). And it also show to html page that i have learn that lesson but I can't find if else condition or maybe i do wrong way.

cshtml code:

```
<ul>
@model List<Project.Models.Lession>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    //if else condition
    if ()
    {
        <li>
            <div class="card-lesson lesson-done">
                <a style="color:black" href="/learning/@item.CourseID/@item.LessionID">
                    <h4><span><img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/20/000000/checked-2--v1.png" /></span>@item.Name</h4>
                    <p class="card-time">4:35</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <hr>
        </li>
    }
    else
    {
        <li>
            <div class="card-lesson">
                <a style="color:black" href="/learning/@item.CourseID/@item.LessionID">
                    <h4>@item.Name</h4>
                    <p class="card-time">10:43</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <hr>
        </li>
    }
}
</ul>
```

controller (I get viewbag to fill in another part of html page)

```cs
[CheckSession]
public ActionResult Index(int courseId, int lessonId)
{
    int userId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["user_id"].ToString());

    var checkUserLearnLesson = from e in db.UserAndLessions 
                               where e.UserID == userId && e.LessionID == lessonId
                               select e;
    //case if user have not learn this lesson before
    if(checkUserLearnLesson.ToList().Count == 0)
    {
        //user learn this lesson
        UserAndLession newUserAndLesson = new UserAndLession()
        {
            UserID = userId,
            LessionID = lessonId,
            Watched = true
        };
        db.UserAndLessions.Add(newUserAndLesson);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    //select all lesson in course
    var learningInfo = from l in db.Lessions
                       where l.CourseID == courseId
                       select l;

    //get data in table lesson
    var lessonInfor = from l in learningInfo where l.LessionID == lessonId select l;

    //case when lesson not existed
    if (lessonInfor.ToList().Count == 0)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Error");
    }

    //case when have at least 1 lesson
    ViewBag.srcVideo = lessonInfor.ToList()[0].Video;
    ViewBag.description = lessonInfor.ToList()[0].Description;
    ViewBag.title = lessonInfor.ToList()[0].Name;

    var courseName = from c in db.Courses where c.CourseID == courseId select c;
    ViewBag.courseName = courseName.ToList()[0].Name;
    
    return View(learningInfo.ToList());
}
```

Database:

[image: Database]

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but this code makes no sense to me. When a user subscribes to a course, you should make a record for each lesson in this course and watched = false. Turning that value true should be done on the Lesson-controller after whatever-logic.

You action-method takes in a CourseId **and** a lessonId, which implies you only want info over one course ..., or one of them is actually redundant.

For your Index-ActionMethod

Your model is of the type UserAndLession

and you fill it up with

```
int userId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["user_id"].ToString());

model = from e in db.UserAndLessions 
                           where e.UserID == userId && e.LessionID == lessonId
                           select e;
```

There's no need for an if in the view. you basically have two columns, lessonId, Completed? who match with  model.LessionId and model.Watched, unless you need it for an icon, you can use a simple if(model.watched) => show icon.

If you want to show all lessons in a course. You add a navigator-property with courses in UserAndLessions-table. Perform a query for a specific UserId and CourseId, as you have done. Your model becomes a `List<UserAndLessions>`, and you fill up your table with @foreach (var item in Model)

If there's some specific lesson-course-logic, please share.

Comment: Take care when writing generics (`List<UserAndLessions>`) - if you don't backtick them, the subtype is interpreted by the Markdown parser as invalid HTML, and it will disappear.